# 1/ Is it that only individuals able to be virtuous "naturally" be deemed really virtuous?

Tags: ethics

Is it that being dependent on external, thought-through, developed-through, things (more or less advanced science and technique, knowledge, developed ethics, etc.) in order to be virtuous makes those individuals less deemed to be considered really virtuous?

In other words, is it that only individuals able to be virtuous "naturally" (without the help of civilization: science/technique/knowledge/school of thought) be deemed to be considered really virtuous?

This is maybe indirectly linked to Rousseau's understanding of human nature, and of civilization, and many authors such as Heidegger who are suspicious about science and technology.

**[It belongs to a series of questions which tackle the relation of idealism-romanticism (1/ naturality, 2/ [the noble soul](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103896/is-it-that-individuals-who-rely-on-favourable-conditions-are-not-deemed-to-be-co), 3/ [spontaneity](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/3-is-it-that-only-individuals-who-are-able-to-spontaneously-act-virtuously-be)) with ethics. Naturality, the noble soul and spontaneity are very different things, so each issue must be investigated separately.]**

Comment: is this the sort of thing you mean "Michael Stocker (1976) originally introduced it as a problem for deontology and consequentialism. He pointed out that the agent who, rightly, visits a friend in hospital will rather lessen the impact of his visit on her if he tells her either that he is doing it because it is his duty or because he thought it would maximize the general happiness. But as Simon Keller observes, she won’t be any better pleased if he tells her that he is visiting her because it is what a virtuous agent would do, so virtue ethics would appear to have the problem too"?

Comment: @prof_post Yes. This is what I was thinking about, but I in fact need to break down my question into three questions. And the last one is about what you mention here: is it that only individuals who are **spontaneously** acting virtuously be considered virtuous?

Comment: yes there seems to be a few components to both your questions. good luck arranging your thoughts hah

Comment: "spontaneously" meaning "without premeditation or external stimulus."

Comment: are you really asking how anyone can be virtuous if they make mistrakes and are imperfect? you might want to look into (mahayana) buddhism and the perfection of character, if so

Comment: @prof_post I think my questions are investigating the idealistic and romantic approach to morality (spontaneity, nature, and noble, almost aristocratic ideals and feelings, being their important values).

Comment: ah that's interesting, if you want to  make sure you are not closed, then maybe add some of your present ideas/research etc. that generated your question. that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it that only individuals who are able to "spontaneously" act virtuously be deemed to be considered virtuous?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/is-it-that-only-individuals-who-are-able-to-spontaneously-act-virtuously-be-de)

Comment: @prof_post I added some precision about the philosophical/cultural background in each question

Comment: @DavidGudeman No, these are 3 different questions: morality with relation to nature, spontaneity and matter-above noble ideals and feelings

Comment: @DavidGudeman "matter-above noble ideals and feelings" which could be encompassed as "noble soul" (in sharp contrast with utilitarian material calculus)

Comment: I don't write the text, I just vote to close. My vote isn't changing.

Comment: I'm not sure what "science/technique/knowledge" has to do with virtue. It's also very vague. Technique for what? Did you mean technology? That certainly fits with science, but that would leave me more confused about what that has to do with virtue. Also, babies don't know anything. Can they be virtuous? (The general consensus seems to be "no", exactly because they don't know anything.) Science and technology (and arguably knowledge) are tools, that allow you to act more effectively. That has nothing to do with the motivation behind your actions.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Rousseau thought ethics (the goodness of human nature) through the relationship of humans with progress, believing that progress led people being **less** virtuous

Comment: he also stressed the noble spontaneity of the child, which implies to make a lesser use of science and technique in our lives, which includes interrational relationships

Answer (score 1):

One of the distinctions in levels-of-virtue that Aristotle draws is that between the [continently virtuous and the strictly virtuous](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-ethics/#VirtDefiContInco):

> (A) Some agents, having reached a decision about what to do on a particular occasion, experience some counter-pressure brought on by an appetite for pleasure, or anger, or some other emotion; and this countervailing influence is not completely under the control of reason. (1) Within this category, some are typically better able to resist these counter-rational pressures than is the average person. **Such people are not virtuous, although they generally do what a virtuous person does.** Aristotle calls them “continent” (*enkratês*). [emphasis added]

Just before that, in the same article, they say:

> All free males are born with the potential to become ethically virtuous and practically wise, but to achieve these goals they must go through two stages: during their childhood, they must develop the proper habits; and then, when their reason is fully developed, they must acquire practical wisdom (*phronêsis*). This does not mean that first we fully acquire the ethical virtues, and then, at a later stage, add on practical wisdom. Ethical virtue is fully developed only when it is combined with practical wisdom (1144b14–17). A low-grade form of ethical virtue emerges in us during childhood as we are repeatedly placed in situations that call for appropriate actions and emotions; but as we rely less on others and become capable of doing more of our own thinking, we learn to develop a larger picture of human life, our deliberative skills improve, and our emotional responses are perfected. Like anyone who has developed a skill in performing a complex and difficult activity, the virtuous person takes pleasure in exercising his intellectual skills. Furthermore, when he has decided what to do, he does not have to contend with internal pressures to act otherwise. He does not long to do something that he regards as shameful; and he is not greatly distressed at having to give up a pleasure that he realizes he should forego.

So if you are asking for the Aristotelian picture of these things, there you go. Presumably, however, the Platonic/Socratic picture is rather different: we have by our empirical nature "forgotten" the Form of the Good, and it is not our empirical but our rational nature that is called to remember this Thing. Kant in *The Metaphysics of Morals* talks about our having two "selves," an intelligible and a physical one, and then in the *Religion* he says that our hearts are corrupt "by nature," even though our *will* by *its* nature is *not* so corruptible. Or then John Rawls, despite not being a perfectionist, will speak in sec. 40 of *A Theory of Justice* about actions that "express our true nature," and these come out as virtues in the end.

Comment: I feel the last paragraph (about Plato, Kant and Rawls) fits to this question https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103896/2-is-it-that-individuals-who-rely-on-favourable-conditions-are-not-deemed-to-be

Comment: @Starckman I thought this question was about being virtuous by nature???

Comment: I feel these authors (Plato, Kant, Rawls) are more idealistic, which has more to see with the "noble soul". For instance, you explained that it is through "ideas" that Plato wishes that we recover our true good nature (in opposition to empirical observation of the material reality).

Comment: Kant seems also to hold this idealistic view, with the "intelligible" self. (for Rawls I am not sure)

Comment: @Starckman the idealism/naturalism distinction is an unclear one, usually not even set up directly between those terms, and quite blurred (to the point of almost total uselessness) here.