# 2/ Is it that individuals who rely on favourable conditions are not deemed to be considered really virtuous?

Tags: ethics

Is it that only individuals able to be virtuous even in adverse conditions (psychological and/or physical discomfort) can be deemed to be considered as really virtuous?

In other words, is it that individuals who rely on favourable conditions (psychological and/or physical comfort) in order to be virtuous are not deemed to be considered really virtuous?

This is maybe indirectly related to the spartan philosophy, as valued in Nietzsche, Baudelaire, etc.

And to the (maybe centuries-long view) that sees morality as a matter-above noble ideals and feelings. "Matter-above noble ideals and feelings" which could be encompassed as the "noble soul" (in sharp contrast with utilitarian, often materialist (in the philosophical sense), calculus).

The most illustrative case being Jesus Christ, who was able to be highly virtuous, even in extremely aversive physical and psychological conditions, for him having a sacred soul.

**[It belongs to a series of questions which tackle the relation of idealism-romanticism (1/ [naturality](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103895/is-it-that-only-individuals-able-to-be-virtuous-naturally-be-deemed-really-vir), 2/ the noble soul, 3/ [spontaneity](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/3-is-it-that-only-individuals-who-are-able-to-spontaneously-act-virtuously-be)) with ethics.
Naturality, the noble soul and spontaneity are very different things, so each issue must be investigated separately.]**

Comment: i've never encountered such an explicit claim, but it makes sense.

Comment: is it a reference to the Kantian argument that people who do what morality requires but out of self interest (like being charitable because they feel good about it) are not acting morally ?

Comment: @armand Yes, there is certainly some link with Kantian ethics I think, thx for bringing that :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it that only individuals who are able to "spontaneously" act virtuously be deemed to be considered virtuous?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/is-it-that-only-individuals-who-are-able-to-spontaneously-act-virtuously-be-de)

Comment: People tend to perceive themselves to be in an unfavorable position by default, e.g. as compared to richer people. "Keeping up with the Jones", so not clear to me that your criteria works. But if you really want to test a person's moral fiber, give him/her power.

Comment: @armand I quote your comment in this question https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/103901/is-it-that-only-individuals-who-are-able-to-spontaneously-act-virtuously-be-de?noredirect=1#comment312156_103901

Comment: @Olivier5 Was thinking really about psychological and physical conditions, not economic or sociological conditions. I understand that you imply (certainly correctly) that economic and sociological conditions might lead to adverse psychological and physical conditions, but a focus is needed here.

Comment: Well, I don't think hardship corrupts people, though it might damage them, ie break their trust in other folks. But certainly, power corrupts. That's what I meant.

Comment: @Olivier5 I agree that power corrupts

Comment: "The most illustrative case being Jesus Christ" ... as long as you assume that he had sufficient knowledge of what his actions would lead to and/or he considered the personal benefits of his actions to outweigh the risks or drawbacks (being revered by others is quite a benefit). I would've added "and the Bible is true", but I suppose you can talk about the character regardless of how much of the story is fictional (although that might lead to confusion about what you're talking about, and this distracts from the fact that many people believe it's true and base many things in life on that).